# Overriding CSS in wordpress using class

Tags: css, wordpress

I try to override the `<h1>` style in WordPress using class but failed.

```
.block-h1  { font-size:13px; font-size:1.1em; line-height:13px; position:absolute; top:13%; left:6%; z-index:99; color: #E35094; !important;}
```

There is a tag `<h1 class="block-h1">Hello</h1>` in page, all style of block-h1 are removed when loading by WordPress and style is kept as the .post-content h1.

I do use the `!important` but not work.

Comment: I don't recommend using `!important` but the way you're using it is incorrect. It needs to be after each rule. For example, `color: #E35094 !important;`

Comment: you have a typo, just delete the semicolon before !important . Then again, @j08691 is right, try to avoid !important and use more specific classes

Comment: j08691 and Fabio, thanks for your comment, I wrongly declare above style in the header, I declare them in the footer and all work.

Answer (score 1):

Never use `!important`, it's a blunt tool and makes it difficult to override the new declaration.  Make your declaration *more specific*.

Use a class of:

```
h1.block-h1 { ... }
```

`h1.block-h1` is more specific than `.block-h1` alone.

See: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your css with:

```
h1.block-h1  { 
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
  left: 6%;
  z-index: 99;
  color: #E35094 !important;
}
```